# `use-package` errors with "failed to define function" message when loading a local copy of a package

Tags: use-package, autoload

I'm trying to modify the package `ediprolog`, which was installed and working before, with use-package, from ELPA. I copied the file from the `elpa` folder to a folder called `ediprolog.el` and used:

```
(use-package ediprolog
    :load-path "./extern/")
```

The problem is now I'm getting an error saying

> File mode specification error: (error Autoloading file ~/.emacs.d/extern/ediprolog.el failed to define function ediprolog)

(even with the original code for ediprolog.el). Further, even if I remove the `:load-path` and try to load the package from ELPA, I still get the same error. Also, even though it fails, it seems to find functions like `ediprolog-dwim` which has an autoload cookie and is defined in that file, but they don't work.

(I have tried deleting the `elpa` folder and redownloading all the packages, removing only the ediprolog folder and removing `ediprolog` from the list of selected packages, but still the same results)

How can I make `use-package` load the package properly again?

---

Adding

`;;;###autoload
(defun ediprolog ())`

in the file makes the error go away, but this doesn't seem like the correct thing to do.

Comment: Is ".ediprolog/" a directory in your `user-emacs-directory`? If not, you might need to provide the absolute path to that directory.

Comment: It's finding the file. It's able to pull in at least the names of the functions, like `ediprolog-dwim`

Comment: Are you sure that it is finding the file from that load-path? Could be that `package-initialize` or something is loading your library from elpa. Try to delete the package and only use the use-package declaration. Note that in the elpa directory the file `ediprolog-autoloads.el` is produced during the installation.

Comment: @andrej Please see my edit. I removed it from the list of selected packages and it's still the same

Comment: @Fólkvangr Yes, but how do I fix it? It doesn't say that when loading from elpa

Comment: @Fólkvangr That indeed solved it! I created a folder called ediprolog-1.3 with the file inside and changed the load path to point to that folder and it works. Would you like to post it as an answer? I don't understand why, though

Comment: @Fólkvangr I think the file mode error is because I have prolog mode, which adds itself to the auto load list and then ediprolog hooks onto prolog-mode

Answer (score 1):

Your load path is saying `:load-path "./ediprolog/"`, the error is saying `~/.emacs.d/extern/ediprolog.el` I assume that `ediprolog.el` is found because the directory `~/.emacs.d/extern/` is in the load-path.

In your `use-package` declaration you tell emacs to look for it somewhere else, namely in `~/.emacs.d/.ediprolog/`. I think in your case `(require 'ediprolog)` would be enough, or try `:load-path "/extern"`

The following declaration works for me without any errors:

```
(use-package ediprolog
:load-path "~/extern/ediprolog")
```

Note that here `ediprolog` is a directory in which the file `ediprolog.el` is found.

EDIT: If `ediprolog.el` is in `~/.emacs.d/extern/` then

```
(use-package ediprolog
 :load-path "extern")
```

should work.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my part, I forgot to update that part of the question. Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't solve the problem; yes `require` probably would work, but I want to use `use-package`, because it makes the configuration much cleaner. So, yeah, even after completely purging and reinstalling emacs and cleaning the elpa dir and everything else, I still get this error unless I add an empty definition of a function named `ediprolog`

Comment: So can you update the question and include the minimal part of your configuration that reproduces the error. Also tell us where exactly the file is that you want to load. Is it its own directory or is it in ` ~/.emacs.d/extern/`?  Otherwise it is difficult to help.

Comment: I've updated it already. It's in ~/.emacs.d/extern/ediprolog.el

Comment: It says in the question "I copied the file from the elpa folder to a folder called ediprolog.el" Also is the folder extern already in your load path?

Comment: Thank you for the help, but Fólkvangr 's comment seems to have done the trick. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46345/use-package-errors-with-failed-to-define-function-message-when-loading-a-loc#comment71527_46345 still don't know why, though...